# Faster sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I create a java desktop app which communicates with a server for getting data from mysql.

Currently this query on server:

```
select
    ec_transactions.added,
    ec_transactions.merchant_id,
    ---
    ec_customer_billing_details.card_payment_method,
    ---
    ec_customer_details.first_name,
    ---
    ec_customer_card_details.card_holde r_name,
    ---
from
    ec_transactions,
    ec_customer_billing_details,
    ec_customer_details,
    ec_customer_card_details  
where ec_transactions.transactions_id =  tranId 
  AND ec_customer_billing_details.customer_id =  custId 
  AND ec_customer_details.customer_id   =  custId  
  AND ec_customer_card_details.customer_id =  custId
```

---

is too slow.
**How can i do it faster?**

Comment: Unless you edit your question to make it readable, add some more information as table structures and some data to test, hardly you will get some answer.

Comment: Do you have index on these fields? ec_transactions.transactions_id, ec_customer_billing_details.customer_id, ec_customer_details.customer_id, ec_customer_card_details.customer_id?

Comment: For readability: 1) remove the `"`s, this prevents syntax highlighting. 2) Spacing - put a space or new-line between fields in the select. 3) Shorter lines - as a general rule, avoid code that needs the scrollbar.

Comment: A good developer has always open a notepad or an sql reader :) .you can copy paste it there. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this using the explain plan and setting indixes if not set on you tables, besides you can optimize your query, take a look at [MySql documentation regarding optimizing statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/statement-optimization.html).

Answer (score 0):

The proper indexing of table will help the performance of the query faster. You don't need to create an index manually if the column has been set as *primary key*, *foreign key*, or *unique* because the server automatically creates them for you. But always remember that too much indexes on the tables will decrease the performance of these DML statements such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`.